# Left-aligning rows of flex content

Tags: css, flexbox

Ok, I have been looking and not seeing any questions close enough to extrapolate an answer..

I have a large list (UL / LI) of color options displayed in a flex container, and need to have the columns align to the left. Currently the first row is offset, and I am not seeing how to get it to display like the remaining rows.

I have experimented with the CSS -  padding, margins, justify options, alignments, changing from row to columns, etc. I accept that the CSS may be sloppy, and any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Here is the CSS applied to the page (URL: https://winepaperscissors.com/custom-item-request/):

```
.colors .control-label{
  display: none;
}
.colors {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
}
.colors img {
  width: 10vmin;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  display: block;
}
.colors input[type="radio"]{
    visibility:hidden;
}
.colors input[type="radio"]:checked + img {
    border: #444444 5px solid;
}
```

The entire color selection is in the .colors class, and is an inline unordered list.

Comment: Remove `margin-left: 10px` from your selector `.caldera-grid .radio-inline+.radio-inline`. It's the one adding unnecessary margins that causes the color circles to appear offset from the grid after the first row. Note: please do not link to external sites, because they are subjected to link rot. Try to reproduce your case with minimal code in the question itself instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because all the labels have a `margin-left:10px` except the first one

this part `.caldera-grid .radio-inline + .radio-inline`
 means that the `margin-left:10px` is applied to the labes `.radio-inline` that comes after `.radio-inline`

replace this

`.caldera-grid .checkbox-inline + .checkbox-inline, .caldera-grid .radio-inline + .radio-inline`

with

`.caldera-grid .checkbox-inline + .checkbox-inline, .caldera-grid .radio-inline + .radio-inline, .radio-inline:first-of-type`

to add the `margin-left:10px` to the first `.radio-inline`

or simply replace it with :

`.caldera-grid .checkbox-inline + .checkbox-inline, .caldera-grid .radio-inline`

removing the `+ .rdio-inline`